# Is there a free visual similarity image local hard drive search?

Tags: file-management, search

I'm looking for a desktop search engine for finding images on my local hard drive with high visual similarity. I've only found paid for ones so far. It could be Linux or Windows software; either would be helpful. A Google Desktop plugin would be nice!

My first use case is being able to organise all the processed versions of a photo based on it's original, or finding the original of a processed image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I've 'lost' a photo. I know I have it but I don't know where — how can I find it?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10574/ive-lost-a-photo-i-know-i-have-it-but-i-dont-know-where-how-can-i-find-it)

Comment: That doesn't look like a duplicate from the title, I know, but click on it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the duplicate, there's lots of great information there and I'm now running imgSeek on my archive! :-)  http://www.imgseek.net/

Comment: Some related answers at https://askubuntu.com/questions/4072/how-can-i-find-duplicate-photos

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[ImgSeek](http://www.imgseek.net/) is an open-source project that claims to do this.

[DigiKam](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/digikam-doc/digikam/using-digikam.html#idm1100) is apparently trying to add similar functionality.

[Pixcavator](http://calculus123.com/wiki/Pixcavator_Student_Edition) is not open source, but there is a 30 day free trial.

---

If you're the DIY coder type, I wound up writing the DB-end of a system that allows phash similarity queries over a fairly large image corpus (10M+ images) in <10 ms/image.

It's part of a larger image deduplication system, and rather tightly coupled, but it's all online [here](https://github.com/fake-name/IntraArchiveDeduplicator).

---

**Later Edit:**

I wound up writing a custom PostgreSQL indexing extension to push fuzzy-image-searching into the database. It's open source [here](https://github.com/fake-name/pg-spgist_hamming). It scales up to at least 30 million images without significant issue (I have ~32 million images in my index).

Comment: I'm trying imgSeek but it keeps crashing when I try to add my entire collection , about 20k images. It might get there eventually though and looks quite good

Comment: Yeah. It was last updated in 2006, though.

Comment: imgSeek has since been updated in April 2013.

Comment: ImgSeek just crashed during my first scan. Seems a bit unintuitive to use as well. Just my thoughts.

Answer (score 11):

After looking for a while I found the perfect solution. This program does exactly what I wanted and it's free: http://www.duplicate-finder.com/photo.html

Comment: This "Awesome Duplicate Photo Finder" worked better for me because it was simple enough. VisiPics seems powerful, but I couldn't quickly figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 7):

I've been using [visipics](http://www.visipics.info/index.php?title=Main_Page) which i found out about on [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5535510/clean-up-your-photo-collection-with-free-tools) which works very well.
[image: Visipics]

This is the excerpt from the site

> I recommend VisiPics (pictured above). It scans the actual photo
>   content of each image file, and so can take some time to tally up its
>   findings if you've got a huge, huge database, but you can fairly
>   easily let it run in the background and do your normal browsing and
>   work. Matches are shown together, a sliding scale of matching
>   looseness is offered, and while it's a shareware app with some locked
>   features, it offers enough as a freeware app to do some serious
>   cleaning.
>
> How do you get started with VisiPics? Choose your photo folder from
>   the list in the top-middle row, hit the right-facing arrow with the
>   "+" sign to add it to VisiPics' queue, then hit the Play-style button
>   in the middle to start scanning for duplicates.
>
> Note: If you've previously used Picasa, iPhoto, or other photo
>   management suites to organize and edit your photos, you may find lots
>   and lots of photo duplicates. That's because those applications create
>   folders of "Originals" to allow you to undo changes you make to
>   photos, along with caches of thumbnail images for fast browsing. If
>   you're not using these apps anymore, and you're sure you won't want to
>   undo those changes, go ahead and remove those folders and duplicates.
>   Otherwise, keep them, and remove their folders from your searches.
>
> Speaking of Picasa, Google's photo manager has a "Show Duplicate
>   Photos" option in its Experimental menu, but that's exactly what it
>   is—very experimental, and not all that clear about what you're
>   deleting. You're better off going with an app that makes its findings
>   clear.

Then there's also [dupeguru](https://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru_pe/) from this [answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/453251/16847)

Answer (score 1):

Visipics is an image duplicate utility with an adjustable similarity comparison scale.  You can look for very similar pictures or fairly dissimilar pictures and then delete whichever ones you want.

Answer (score 1):

[Similar.pictures](https://vitali-fedulov.github.io/similar.pictures/) is a browser-based finder of similar photos on your hard drive I developed. It does not allow to delete files, only shows groups of similar images, also as a list of files in text format.

Answer (score 0):

[Geeqie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geeqie), an image browser for Linux and friends, has this functionality, but I've never made serious use of it, so can't vouch for how well it works. It's a great, extremely configurable image browser in general, though.

Answer (score -3):

Try [TinEye](http://www.tineye.com/). They have in-browser plugins -- not desktop. See how it works for you. Also, [Google Image Search](http://images.google.com/) is getting pretty good at this. It's worth taking out for a spin every so often.

Comment: -1 : The OP **specifically** mentions he needs a **local** option.

Comment: +-0: That information was added to the question after this answer was posted.

Comment: @Simon Stelling - I considered that. The local information was added to the *title* after the question was asked. It was **always** in the question body. OP: `I'm looking for a desktop search engine for finding images on my local hard drive with high visual similarity.`