# "Thumbnail based" image search on Mac.../

Tags: thumbnails

I have hard-drives full of old RAW files from photography... I can't find old images that I have smaller processed versions of. Is there a desktop tool for a Mac that can do 'image search.' I will reach out and personally thank anyone who helps...

Regards,
Caleb

Comment: You mean 'find kind=image/jpg' or do you mean 'find 123.raw where 123.jpg exists'? Regular Finder search can do the first, no idea what could do the second.

Comment: @Tetsujin 2nd not too hard with a bash script on OSX (I have a script to re-associate JPG & CR2 when I reorganize my pictures). The only pitfall is that picture names are not unique on a large directory tree that has picture from different cameras.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a free visual similarity image local hard drive search?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14094/is-there-a-free-visual-similarity-image-local-hard-drive-search)

Comment: Thanks. I'm am diligently learning and gaining speed with this stack. I don't have a coding background and I use a Mac: as a newbie I reckon this relegates me to the sticks and I'm out of luck... (?). Thanks.